# payment methods for android application

Tags: android, payment-gateway, billing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement credit card payment in android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564482/how-to-implement-credit-card-payment-in-android-application)

In my android application i have items to be sold, is there any way/sdk for payment by credit card ? Please help me how to develop my application

thanks
santanu

Comment: Please find out your matching sdk from [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/sdk). Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks SPK,I have used paypal sandbox in my application, but I am going to make it live, X.com does not give me APP Id to make it live, so I want to use other payment method or credit card payment.If is there any way, please help me

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564482/how-to-implement-credit-card-payment-in-android-application